# Uncaught ReferenceError: script is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

In jQuery, how do I call a function in a script that I retrieve via code?

I have a javascript file called `testjavascript.js`

Here is the code:

```
function testfunctionwithdata(testdata)
{
    alert(testdata);
}
function testfunction()
{
    alert("testfunction");
}
```

I also have a javascript called `testcalljavascriptfunction.js`

Here is the code:

```
var scripturl = "/objects/testjavascript.js";

$.getScript(scripturl, function() {
   script.testfunction();
});
```

When I load the `testcalljavascriptfunction.js`script from an `index.html` page, I am getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: script is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no object called `script` in your context, when the script file is loaded it is parsed and executed. Since your method seems to be in global context you can call it by using `testfunction()`

```
var scripturl = "/objects/testjavascript.js";

$.getScript(scripturl, function() {
   testfunction();
});
```